# how to @FilterJoinTable with EntityManager in Hibernate JPA?

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I would like to limit the data that is coming from OneToMany relation. In my program the boss account can view all the company's that have orders in the given month and year. The company class can f.e. count the income from these orders. I used @FilterJoinTable but since i have to use EntityManager I cant do it anymore. Here is the code I used with the Session object.

Order class

```
@Entity(name="order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Company company;
private int month;
private int year;
[...]

@JoinColumn(name = "company_idcompany", referencedColumnName = "idcompany")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}
[...]
```

Company class

```
@Entity(name="company")
@FilterDef(name="orderFilter", parameters = {
                       @ParamDef(name = "month", type = "int"),
                       @ParamDef(name = "year", type = "int")
                       })
public class Company implements Serializable 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
[...]

@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy="company"
)
@JoinTable(
        name = "order",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idcompany") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idorder") }
)
@FilterJoinTable(name="orderFilter", condition=":month = month and :year = year")
public List<Order> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}
[...]
```

the get method looked like this

```
public List<Company> get(int month, int year) throws AdException
{
    try
    {
        begin();

        //will get only the orders in given month and year
        Filter filtr = getSession().enableFilter("orderFilter");

        filtr.setParameter("month", month);
        filtr.setParameter("year", year);

        //this criteria didn't work well so I've added a loop below 
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("companyList"));


        List<Company> companys = crit.list();

        Iterator iter = companys.iterator();

        //throwing out the companys that have no orders in given month and year
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Company com = (Company)iter.next();
            if(com.getOrderList().isEmpty())
            {
                companys.remove(com);
                iter = companys.iterator();
            }
        }

        getSession().disableFilter("orderFilter");
        commit();

        return companys;
    }
    catch( HibernateException e )
    {
        rollback();
        throw new AdException("ex message",e);
    }
 }
```

The get method returns only the company's that have orders in given month and year. The orderList in each company contains only the orders from given month and year. I know the get method is not pretty but it worked. Can You please tell me how can I resolve this problem? I am clueless.

**RESOLVED**  thanks to Joshua Davis

```
   Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT o.company FROM Order z WHERE o.month=:month AND z.year=:year");

            q.setParameter("month", month);
            q.setParameter("year", year);

            List<Company> companys = q.getResultList();

            for(Company com : companys)
            {
                Query q2 = em.createQuery("from Order where month = :month and year = :year and company.idCompany = :id");
                q2.setParameter("month", month);
                q2.setParameter("year", year);
                q2.setParameter("id", com.getIdCompany());

                com.setOrderList(q2.getResultList());
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to do this would be:

```
em.createQuery("select o from Order o " +
        "where o.company.id=:id and o.month=:m and o.year=:y")
        .setParameter("id",someCompany.getId())
        .setParameter("y",year)
        .setParameter("m",month)
        .getResultList();
```

Essentially, you are using object graph navigation to solve a problem that is easily solved with a plain JPA query.

If you need to modify the orders in the list, that will work transparently, as the query will return persistent instances.   If you need to add or delete orders, then you might need to access the collection in Firma (company).

Comment: Thank You for the reply but that is not what I'm looking for. I might have asked the question incorrectly. The point of the get function is to return a list of company's that have orders in the given year and month. I need the Company objects because they have some specific functions such as counting the income from the orders in the given month.

Comment: @Szajba You can do that with JPAQL as well: "select distinct o.company from Order o ..."

Comment: Still not working. I did as You wrote: "select distinct o.company from Order o where o.month=:m and o.year=:y". It gives companys that have at least one order in given month and year but also the order list in each company contains the rest of the orders that have different dates. Why is that happening?

Comment: Make sure your filter is defined correctly.   Personally I'm not  a big fan of using filters in this way (to filter collections).   Also, queries and filters behave differently with collections of embeddables as opposed to collections of entities.

Comment: Personally, I would solve this problem without using filters.   I would use one query to get the companies, another query to get the orders for the companies (filtered).   That way I don't have to deal with any large collections lazily loading themselves when I don't want them to.